# Value was either too large or too small for an Int32 in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a singup forum, in which there is aphone number field

code is:

```
try
{
    cz.SignUp(nametxt.Value, passtxt.Value,  
    Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue),  
    Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue),
    Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList3.SelectedValue),
    mailtxt.Value,Convert.ToInt32(numbtxt.Value));
    //GridView1.DataSource=ca.viewadmin();
    Lbe6.Text = ("Signup Success");             
}
catch
{
    lbe5.Text = ("FAILED");
}
```

But when I click on submit the button it shows me an error.
Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.

I also tried uint and int64 but it did not work

Comment: phone numbers aren't ints. they're strings. unless you awnt to treat as `555-555-1234` as "negative 1234" because it'd actually be a subtraction statement.

Comment: Wow, if you presented me with that code for peer-review, I would reject it on formatting reasons alone

Comment: How numbtxt.Value looks like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Phone numbers are not numbers.

You should use a string.

Remember: If you can't add it, it isn't a number.

Answer (score 2):

Phone numbers are not **NUMBERS**

It is better to take `string` for storing the Phone Numbers.

**On a side note:-**

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bkb8w2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Integer variables are stored as signed 32-bit (4-byte) integers
>   ranging in value from -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647.

And [INT32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx)

> Int32 is an immutable value type that represents signed integers with
>   values that range from negative 2,147,483,648 (which is represented by
>   the Int32.MinValue constant) through positive 2,147,483,647 (which is
>   represented by the Int32.MaxValue constant. The .NET Framework also
>   includes an unsigned 32-bit integer value type, UInt32, which
>   represents values that range from 0 to 4,294,967,295.